# XAML: UniformGrid where you can define cells as not unifrom in size?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, styles, itemscontrol

As a part of an `ItemsControl` style I'd like to have something that works similar ot `Grid/UniformGrid` as an `ItemsPanel`.

In its simplest form, the `Style` would look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and I would use it like this:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ItemsControl>
                <TextBlock Text="Label1:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="ThisWillBeBound" />
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl>
                <TextBlock Text="Label2:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="ThisWillBeBound" />
            </ItemsControl>
                            <ItemsControl>
                <TextBlock Text="Label3:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="ThisWillBeBound" />
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl>
                <TextBlock Text="Label4:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="ThisWillBeBoundButIsSomewhatLongerThenTheOtherProperties" />
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl>
                <TextBlock Text="Label5:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="ThisWillBeBound" />
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl>
                <TextBlock Text="Label6:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="ThisWillBeBound" />
            </ItemsControl>
        </WrapPanel>
```

As you can see, you would throw a `Label` for a property into this plus a binding to that property and they would stick together even if things would wrap around becuase of different sizes of the app window for example.

The nice thing here about the`UniformGrid` is that it seems that if one `Label` is longer the others will get the same space meaning the bound properties would line up neatly (why this happens I don't understand because these should be seperate `UniformGrid`s I guess). Problem here is that the cell width of the `Label` part and the `Property` part is the same, so if the property is long there will be a large gap between the `Label` and the `Property`.

Using normal `Grid` instead would mean I'd have to set the `Grid.Column="0"` and `Grid.Column="1"` everyplace I put items into this `ItemsControl`. That's not really what I wan't.

Is there a way for me to have some sort of grid that lines up like the uniform one but doesn't stratch all columns when one only needs to be and assumes you are putting into columns the same way you declare the items?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've typically seen this sort of scenario handled is via a combination of Grid+IsSharedSizeScope+ListView+DataTemplate.
In this case, the label text (i.e. "Label1:") and entry text (i.e. "ThisWillBeBound") would be in a single item type and a collection of that type of item would be bound to the list view. The Grid.IsSharedSizeScope allows for sharing column size info between different entries while using a template - very handy.
There's a great example of this at http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html. Is this the sort of scenario you're looking for?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this IsSharedSizeScope property and that might come in handy depending of how it works. Abstracting the properties into a object with a label and the property can be a good idea but in this case I'm exposing properties on a Model and It could get a little complicated, especially since some properties will be picked using a combobox and so on.

Comment: One problem using IsSharedSizeScope is that when I wrap it around the second columns of wrap retain the width of the first column. This doesn't happen with the UniformGrid. This is pretty annoying, Grid vs. UniformGrid each has it's different issues.